# Add column to show a weight according to variable counts

Tags: r, statistics

In R, I'm trying to assign a weight in my survey according to how many times a publisher appears in my data and weight it so that each record will represent each publisher equally

Say I have a data frame like this:

`ID  site
1  publisherA
2  PublisherB
3  PublisherC
4  PublisherA
5  PublisherD`

I would like to append a column to this frame that has a weight depending on over/underrepresentation of the site where the data came from:

`site        weight
1  publisherA  0.625 #publisher A appears 2/5 times and is weighted to match 1/4 (4 publishers)
2  PublisherB  1.25 #publisher B appears 1/5 times and is weighted to match 1/4
3  PublisherC  1.25
4  PublisherA  0.625
5  PublisherD  1.25`

I'm also using a the weights package and anesrake package on another set of data for raking, but i feel like there's a simpler way to do this one task instead of raking on one variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ave` to group by `site` and count the appearance of each publisher.

```
NROW(df)/ave(seq_along(df$ID), df$site, FUN = length)/length(unique(df$site))
#[1] 0.625 1.250 1.250 0.625 1.250
```

---

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(ID = 1:5, site = c("PublisherA", "PublisherB", 
"PublisherC", "PublisherA", "PublisherD")), .Names = c("ID", 
"site"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `table`

```
df$weight <- with(df, c((length(site)/table(site)/length(unique(site)))[site]))
df$weight
#[1] 0.625 1.250 1.250 0.625 1.250
```